# Flex taking over load library from Java

Tags: java, android, c++, apache-flex, shared-libraries

My application uses Flex, Java and C++. The C++ code is compiled into a shared library. Java executes methods in the library. After that the Flex code uses the library to use other functions.

The problem is that the methods used by Flex can ONLY be used after the Java code is done with the library.

So is it possible that after Java is done Flex loads the same shared library (in other words: uses the same instance) so they can use the same static functions/variables? It is not possible to execute all of the functions only with Flex or Java.

The final application is a mobile AIR application for Android. Flex SDK version i'm using is 4.6 which deploys with Adobe AIR 3.1
Flex creates an extensioncontext to a Java library. That Java library uses JNI to communicate with the C++ library. That works fine. After Java has assigned a lot of static variables in the C++ library I want Flex to have the ability to use the same instance of the C++ library. So that if Flex calls a function from the library it uses the same static variables with the same values as Java had assigned before.

My idea was to create a second extensioncontext to the java library which passes the "creation" on to the C++ library. Native C/C++ use pointers to methods for Flex to use them. Java gives an instance of an object. But maybe it's possible to catch the initialize request in Java en send it through to C++

Comment: This question is a bit confusing.  You may consider adding additional information.  For example, since you tagged this as Android does that mean you are building an AIR Mobile Application?  If so, that is good information to include as part of your question text.  Specify the version of AIR and Flex you are using too.  In AIR; You can use Native Extensions to access APIs not exposed via Flex; however usually those Native Extensions must be written in Native code; which for Android is Java not C++.

Comment: I've edited my question with more information so it's a bit less confusing I hope. What you say about the native extensions being written in the native code of the platform (like Java being 'the' language for native code on android) isn't true. Before I succesfully tested a Flex native extension written in C++ so it is possible :)